# vim background I/O

Tags: vim

Is there a way to make vim do I/O in the background? When I do a write sometimes my hard disk spins for a few seconds (sometimes almost a full minute) before vim responds again. I've tried a handful of options like

```
set nobackup  
set nowritebackup  
set noswapfile  
set nofsync
```

But they don't seem to help much.

Comment: Are you editing extremely large files? If not, then this sounds more like a hardware/OS problem rather than a vim problem.

Comment: The files are not that large, the hard disk is quite slow. I was hoping to solve the problem easily in vim without resorting to more drastic measures.

Comment: With your hardware responding like that, you may have drastic measures foisted upon you sooner than you might like. I'd solve the *problem* first, rather than trying to work around it.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill You will get just the same problem if you run `rsync` on a large bunch of small files (so that it will require HDD to seek a lot). Missing possibility to do asynchronous actions *is* a vim problem.

Comment: Do you, additionnally, have any autocmds for `BufWritePost`?

Answer (score 4):

No, no background IO in Vim.

And instead of tinkering the symptoms you should cure the cause of your harddisk problems.

Comment: Your commentary is unwanted. Nor is this really an answer.

Comment: "no" is an (valid) answer to "Is there a way to make vim do I/O in the background?" .. if you dont like "no" doesnt make it a no-answer.